# Issue In platform event after Insert Calling twice due to Process builder

Tags: apex, trigger, platform-event, recursion

I have created one platform event and publishing the json in it on account creation.
I  have one Process builder which populating the field on account creation.

the issue is my Platform event is getting inserted twice and json is also generating twice.
My requirement is to genereate the json after PB fires and populate the value in json also.

I have After Insert Trigger for platform event .Please suggest how to acheive this

Comment: Would you please include the details of your solution here, such as the relevant code excerpts and/or a screenshot of your Process configuration? It's hard to completely follow your description without this information. Do you have other triggers or automation on Account that could be causing save recursion?

Comment: correct i have ProcessBuilder which is updating the field and due to this trigger is firing again

Comment: is there any way where i can enforce to run trigger after calling process builder only not before

Comment: No, there is not. You'll need to somehow restructure your functionality. I would be happy to write an answer to this question, but as I mentioned above, you need to add some more details.